# ASP.Net MVC _Layout.cshtml changes not applying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

So my application's default layout creates a link to homepage that is I assume determined by either bootstrap or one of javascript files. Anyway, this is the code currently for my layout:

**Layout CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Delivery</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Delivery</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I removed all the references to bootstrap and js files that I have hoping to get rid of the links showing up, however whenever I execute my application, I end up with this above the view that I made:

**Page code when it's ran**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> - Delivery</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Is there somewhere else besides the layout file I have to make changes in order for this not to run?

EDIT:

**View Code**

```
@using System;
@using Dostava.Data.Models;

@model Dostava.Data.ViewModel.KorisnikViewModel
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KorisnikMenu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        Dobrodosli: <br />
        @Model.Korisnik.KorisnickoIme
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menubtn">
            <input type="button" value="Nova narudzba" onclick="location.href='/Home/Glavna'" />
        </div>
        <div class="menubtn">
            <input type="button" value="Obavijesti" onclick="location.href='/Home/Glavna'" />
        </div>
        <div class="menubtn">
            <input type="button" value="Izmjena podataka" onclick="location.href='/Home/Edit?id=@Model.Korisnik.Id'" />
        </div>
        <div class="menubtn">
            <input type="button" value="Log out" onclick="location.href='/Home/Glavna'" />
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="filter">
        Pretraga narudžbi:
        <hr style="border:1px solid black;" />
        Aktivne   <input type="checkbox" value="Aktivne" /> 
        Zavrsene  <input type="checkbox" value="Zavrsene" />
        Na cekanju <input type="checkbox" value="NaCekanju" />
        Otkazane  <input type="checkbox" value="Otkazane" /> 
        Neuspjesne <input type="checkbox" value="Neuspjesne" />
        <input type="text" id="sifratxt" placeholder="Sifra narudzbe..."  style="width:20%;"/>
        <input type="button" id="filterbtn" value="Primjeni filter" style="width:20%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="narudzbe">
        <hr style="border:1px solid black;" />
        <p style="font-size:18px;">Vaše narudžbe:</p>
        <table class="tabela">
            <tr id="tabelatr">
                <td>Sifra Narudzbe</td>
                <td>Datum Narudzbe</td>
                <td>Primaoc</td>
                <td>Status Naruzdbe</td>
                <td>Cijena Narudzbe</td>
                <td>Detalji Narudzbe</td>
                <td>Otkazi</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Narudzbe n in Model.narudzbe)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@n.SifraNarudzbe</td>
                    <td>@n.DatumNarudzbe</td>
                    <td>@n.Primaoc.Ime @n.Primaoc.Prezime </td>
                    <td>@n.StatusNarudzbe.Naziv</td>
                    <td>@n.CijenaNarudzbe</td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Detalji" onclick="location.href='/Home/DetaljiNarudzbe?id=@n.Id'"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Otkazi" onclick="location.href='/Home/OtkaziNarudzbu?id=@n.Id'"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

**View_Start code**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: What links are showing up ? there must be some code to generate some anchor tag. Remove/comment that.

Comment: You should add @RenderBody() in your Layout view....

Comment: please add the code for the view

Comment: Link that shows up at top is the default link that happens when I run the application, which would eventually lead to login page. Besides the layout file, which I've heavily edited, I don't know where else to look.

Comment: WhatAmIDoing, after getting css format your view contains "links". Are these links those you didn't know where they came from?

Comment: No, the link that's bothering me appears in the header part of the page, and it's automatically being created because bootstrap is being included someplace, and I don't know where, because I've removed it from layout page in code.  https://imgur.com/a/pJiMB Is what I get when I run the page, the circled red thing is being created on its own, and below you can see bootstrap and jquery being called and I don't know where the call is coming from.

Comment: @WhatAmIDoing, why do you think your view is using this Layout? Is that the default layout? please check `Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml` Otherwise there should be a reference to the layout in the view or it's being passed from the action method. Also the content of a view that uses layout shouldn't be a full page but the chunk that is being inserted into the layout. Otherwise you'll get kinda nested html with duplicate sections.

Comment: I added the View Start code in Edit 2, it just leads to the layout which code I posted above already.

Comment: @WhatAmIDoing, when you return you view from the controller, what are the parameters?

Comment: A ViewModel called model, which has classes in it needed for page to work and the view itself.          

  return View("Pocetna", model);

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title> - Delivery</title>
   <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know where this code is being created at, I've posted the layout code above it, the one below is what I get once the page is running. That's what's bothering me.

Comment: check in the " _ViewStart.cshtml" that which layout is applyed on top...

Comment: @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

This is all I get, and the URL leads right back to the file I originally edited

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pJiMB

All the extra stuff is what I circled in red. Container body-content has what I've created myself which should be there. Also evidently, jquery and bootstrap are being invoked despite me removing them from layout page.

Comment: remove "Dostava" link & clear browser history and try